# How to implement notification number on buttons in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am making a jquery mobile app. I want to add a notification number to a button defined like this.

```
<a id="resource-button" href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="left">Resources</a>
```

Basically I want it so that, if the number is > 0, then it should look like this:

[image]

And if its = 0, then the number icon should not show at all.

How can I implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gwqn2eqa/

//HTML

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li><a href="http://www.shreerangpatwardhan.blogspot.com">Spatial Unlimited</a>
        <div class="ui-li-count">158</div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://shreerangpatwardhan.blogspot.in/p/code-samples.html">Google Maps API Examples</a>
        <div class="ui-li-count">0</div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://shreerangpatwardhan.blogspot.in/p/jquery-mobile.html">Jquery Mobile Examples</a>
        <div class="ui-li-count">1</div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/SpatialUnlimited">Facebook likes - Spatial Unlimited</a>
        <div class="ui-li-count">12</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

//JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.each($('.ui-li-count'), function (i, v) {
        if($(this).html() == 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

without listview :

//html

```
<span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-corner-all countBubl">12</span>
```

//css

```
.countBubl {float:left;margin-top:-42px;margin-left:35px;background:#ed1d24;color:#fff;padding:2px;}
```

Comment: This is pretty good. Is there a way to do it without putting it in a listview?

Comment: How do I add in countBubl with the button tag?

Answer (score 3):

HTML

```
<div id="icon">
    <div id="not">3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#icon
{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#bbb;
    position:relative;

}
#not
{
    position:absolute;
    top:-10px;
    right:-10px;
    background-color:#f00;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius:20px
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    text-align:center;
    border:2px solid #fff;

}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($("#not").html()=="0") $("#not").hide();  
});
```

Attached [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gptnxn2j/)

Comment: But how does this integrate with the button tag I defined above?

Comment: I dont understand what above piece of `<a ... > Resource </a>` is about? And what you want to achieve with this. Is this the icon or the notification number

Comment: It is how you define buttons in jquery mobile. See this http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.1/docs/buttons/buttons-types.html. I want to add a notification number on `that` button.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to make row in your database to check post is seen or not for example we get it as `status` with **true** and **false** values .

When user send a new message you add it to database with status false. it's means user already don't see message .
in your code we add new attribute for `<a>` link as `notification`

```
<a id="resource-button" notification="4" href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="left">Resources</a>
```

in this case we have 4 new notificcation for user .

first of all we have to check if notification attribute exists or is not equal to 0 then we make notifi box .

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

if( $("#resource-button").hasAttr("notification")) { 
    var num = $("#resource-button").val("notification") ; 
    if (num > 0) { 
        $("#number").css("display", "block") ; 
        $("#number").text(num); 
    }
}
});
```

CSS for #number :

```
    #number { 
height: 18px;
width: 18px;
background: url("../images/notification-bg-clear.png") no-repeat scroll center center #F56C7E;
position: absolute;
right: 5px;
top: -10px;
color: #FFF;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
text-align: center;
font-size: 9px;
line-height: 18px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) inset, 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
border-radius: 9px;
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: This hardcodes certain positions of the icon. jquery mobile adjusts button sizes depending on the screen size/density. Does this account for that?

Comment: You can use you css for display notifications you can do anything that you have to do with this code

Comment: @omega also you can use Jquery mobile buttoms

Comment: You didn't really answer my question. It looks like you are fixing the positions for a certain dimension. What I want is for it to work when the button is any dimensions.

Comment: I am using jquery mobile buttons. I just want to customize one to add a number on top dynamically.